# Why do we have to make "peinlich" start with a capital letter and also end with -s in this sentence?

Tags: adjective, noun

I just watched a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJPYCZnTtWI). At 0:27, he says:

> So, hast du schon irgendwas sehr Peinliches gemacht, wo du.....

My question is: why do we have to start "peinlich" with a capital letter? It is an adjective here. Also, why it ends with -s? Is it because of adjective ending?

Comment: One *could* (just barely) parse "Hast du schon irgendetwas peinlich gemacht?", namely either with *peinlich* used adverbially ("Have you done anthing in an awkward way?") or denoting the result of "machen" ("Is there anything that you made awkward (=turned into a state of being an awkward thing)?"); here, the weird construction "etwas peinlich machen" would be parallel to "Holz klein hacken", "Draht krumm biegen", "die Flasche leer trinken". But neither of these two interpretations would make sense.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you see here is what is called *Substantivierung* - An adjective is elevated to a noun (dt: *Substantiv*)

> das Peinliche

("the embarrassing") is used as a noun in the sentence (after all, it is the object of the sentence) and thus has to be capitalised.

The -s suffix is used in your example because of the "etwas" which enforces mixed declension.

Comment: @Dennis: Please not that even when using an adjective as adjective (and not as substantive) the endings of the adjective may change: The endings change in the case that the adjectives are describing a substantive (but without using the verb "*sein*"). Example: "*Die Kleider sind peinlich.*" (use of the verb "*sein*"), but: "*Er hat die peinlich**en** Kleider angezogen.*"

Comment: But note that no capitalization takes place when there is an implied substantive, e.g.: *Ich habe das hübsche Kleid angezogen, das peinliche habe ich zu Hause gelassen.*

Comment: @rha I was already afraid that my answer had too much information for the level of the question...

Comment: That's interesting. In English, I believe one would typically analyze the corresponding phrase "anything very embarrassing" as a noun phrase with "anything" as the head and "very embarrassing" as an adjective phrase modifying it. I assume in German it's analyzed differently?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Well, you could get rid of the "anything" - in that case, there's not much difference  to German - Think about the book "The Shining", for example.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly nominalize adjectives in English, too. But one would not normally consider "embarrassing" to be nominalized in "anything (very) embarrassing". You can't remove "anything" from the OP's sentence in English, anyway: \*"Have you done very embarrassing?" is not grammatical. (\*"Have you done _the_ embarrassing?" would _technically_ be grammatical, but still not idiomatic, since "embarrassing" is not commonly nominalized like that.) Anyway, I just found the different analysis of these seemingly parallel constructions in German and English curious.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Agree. But that's not so much a difference in options for nominalization, but rather the difference between usage of the pronouns *anything* and *etwas*

Comment: Just to flog this moribund horse a bit more, it does seems to me that, even in German, the nominalization of adjectives after _etwas_, _nichts_, etc. is perhaps not quite the same things as the "true" nominalization in e.g. _das Peinliche_. If the "nominalized adjective" after _etwas_ was really acting as a true noun, it should be possible to replace it with an actual noun, like, say, _Kartoffel_ or _Wasser_. But while my German is kind of rusty, I'm pretty sure that \*_etwas Kartoffel_ is not grammatical.

Comment: ... Anyway, I agree that _etwas Peinliches_ is still officially considered a nominalized form, and thus capitalized. I'm just saying that it doesn't seem to be quite the same thing as a "normal" nominalized adjective.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen "Nehmen Sie doch noch etwas Kaffee - Etwas Milch dazu?" is perfectly grammatical. I guess you won't object "Kaffee" and "Milch" are nouns.

Comment: A famous example: “Blessed are the meek: for they shall inherit the earth” is “Selig sind die **Sanftmütigen**; denn sie werden das Erdreich besitzen” (emphasis added) in the [2017 Lutherbibel](https://www.bibleserver.com/text/LUT/Matthäus5).  Here *the meek* corresponds to *die Sanftmütigen* — an adjective used as a substantive, in both languages, and getting capitalised in the German.

Comment: @tofro That's a totally different usage. _Etwas Kaffee_ cannot be a lot of coffee, it's _some coffee_. _Etwas Peinliches_ can be a whole lot of embarassing, it's _something embarassing_.

Comment: Since when can nouns be increased with "sehr"?